# How can I create cross platform icon in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am building a signup form and I want to add icons but the icon should look different on different platform for example If I use **Ionicons** it should show ios-person on ios device and md-person on android devices.
How can I build a custom component like that so I just import it in my **Signup screen form** and add a icon based on text input like an person for name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could determine the icon based on the platform, like so:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

<Ionicons
  name={Platform.select({
    ios: 'ios-person',
    android: 'md-person',
  })}
/>
```

If the only difference is `ios` and `md`.

```
<Ionicons 
  name={`${Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios" : "md"}-person`}
/>
```

A re-usable component perhaps,

```
const Icon = ({ name }) => (
  <Ionicons 
    name={`${Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios" : "md"}-${name}`}
  />
)

// Usage
<Icon name="person" />
```

Once more, this assumes the only thing different is `ios` and `md`.

**Edit**

Updating the `name` and `size` depending on each platform can be done like so

```
<Ionicons
  {
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        name: 'ios-person',
        size: 25,
      },
      android: {
        name: 'md-person',
        size: 35
      }
    })
  }
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!! I used the first method. I am also trying to change the size of icon based on platform I used this method for size.  size={Platform.select({
    ios: '24',
    android: '34', })}
    however its not working on android while it runs perfectly on ios I tried on snack

Comment: @user9824674 - Check the last snippet, it'll change the name and the size. I would personally create a re-usable component (like the third snippet)

Comment: You are right!! A customized reusable component will always good But how do I add Size in the 3rd? am I using the right way or size? size={`${Platform.OS === "ios" ? "25" : "35"}-${size}`}